# Building a tree in Java

Tags: java, tree

I'm a newbie in Java. I want to build a tree with one root node and multiple children nodes with some weight on each branch. Can somebody help me in this.

Comment: Be more specific. What have you tried? What problems are you having exactly? Show us that you don't simply want us to do you work for you.

Answer (score 7):

Sample code:

```
class Node {
    public int weight;
    public List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node> ();
}

Node root = new Node ();
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just a sketch to get you started, and could be improved a lot. But your basic members could be as follows:

```
public class WeightedTree {
   private double weight;
   private List<WeightedTree> children;
}
```

I don't want to write more in case it's a homework question, but if you have specific follow up feel free to comment.

Comment: While functional, I think it's not a good idea to name node objects as trees... so maybe call it WeightedTreeNode instead?